# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**I am getting this JavaScript error:**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null

**Here is the code:**

Mds-iMac:cmscart imac$ nodemon app
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app app.js`
(node:2274) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
(node:2274) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
Server started on port 3200
Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.
Connected to MongoDB

```
events.js:182
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null

at /Users/imac/Desktop/cmscart/routes/pages.js:17:24
at model.Query.<anonymous> (/Users/imac/Desktop/cmscart/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4074:16)
at /Users/imac/Desktop/cmscart/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
at /Users/imac/Desktop/cmscart/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

**The page.js code is:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Get Page model
var Page = require('../models/page');

/*
 * GET /
 */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {

Page.findOne({slug: 'home'}, function (err, page) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);

    res.render('index', {
        title: page.title,
        content: page.content
    });
});

});

/*
 * GET a page
 */
router.get('/:slug', function (req, res) {

var slug = req.params.slug;

Page.findOne({slug: slug}, function (err, page) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);

    if (!page) {
        res.redirect('/');
    } else {
        res.render('index', {
            title: page.title,
            content: page.content
        });
    }
});


});

// Exports
module.exports = router;
```

**The error is occuring inside the JavaScript functions at** title: page.title, **above.**

**Please help me out.**

Answer (score 2):

```
router.get('/edit-page/:slug', (req, res) => {
  Page.findOne({slug : req.params.slug}).then((page) => {
    if(!page) { //if page not exist in db
      return res.status(404).send('Page not found');
    }
    res.render('admin/edit_page', { //page  exist
      title: page.title,
      slug: page.slug,
      content: page.content,
      id: page._id
    });
  }).catch((e) => {//bad request 
    res.status(400).send(e);
  });
});
```

Use this code it will work the logic is same but i have handled the conditions using promises it definitely worked for me. Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

It means that when

`function (err, page) {`

was called, inside of `Page.findOne`, the `page` argument did not have a property of `title`.

(without context of how `Page.findOne` is being used, hard to say how to fix it)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (err)
   console.log(err);
```

Is one issue.  When you get an error you should return an http error then exit the function eg:

```
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.statusCode = 500;
    res.end('error');
}
```

When there is an error the `page` variable will be null, which explains the exception thrown.

Comment: I use your code but it does not fix the problem. Any idea?